# Were more than a half of all Silicon Valley tech companies founded by immigrants between 1995 and 2005?

Tags: economics

Source: [CNN Global Public Square](http://globalpublicsquare.blogs.cnn.com/2012/10/03/why-silicon-valley-is-losing-its-luster/):

> A new book caught my eye this week. It’s called *The Immigrant Exodus* by Vivek Wadhwa, a former tech entrepreneur who now studies and lectures on immigration. He has some fascinating findings. Wadhwa says between 1995 and 2005, more than a half of all Silicon Valley tech companies were founded by immigrants.

Were  more than a half of all Silicon Valley tech companies founded by immigrants between 1995 and 2005?

Comment: Well, unless they are started by Native Americans, they are all started by immigrants ;-)

Comment: @vartec Even they immigrated from Asia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Were more than a half of all Silicon Valley tech companies founded by immigrants between 1995 and 2005?" Yes, it seems so.

> "Over half (52.4%) of Silicon Valley startups had one or more
>   immigrants as a key  founder, compared with the California average of
>   38.8%." (p. 5)

This is, however, much higher than the average in the U.S:

> In 25.3% of these companies [average of all U.S. states], at least one
>   key founder was foreign-born. States  with an above-average rate of
>   immigrant-founded companies include California  (39%), New Jersey
>   (38%), Georgia (30%), and Massachusetts (29%). Belowaverage states
>   include Washington (11%), Ohio (14%), North Carolina (14%),  and Texas
>   (18%).  (p.4)

The notes below probably explains the peak in Silicon Valley:

> Almost 80% of immigrant-founded companies in the US were within just two 
>   industry fields: software and innovation/manufacturing-related services. (p.4)

![Chart 6: Breakdown of Engineering and Technology Companies Founded by 
Immigrants from 1995 to 2005 by Industry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqjhu.png)

While...

> It is noteworthy that immigrants from China and India both constitute much less than 1% 
>   of the total U.S. population. (p.6)

... Indians account for more than 25% of engineering and technology immigrant founders.
[image: Chart 1: Birthplace of Engineering and Technology Immigrant Founders]

They also seem to have their fair share in PCT applications:

![Chart 10: Intellectual Property Contributions of U.S. Immigrant Non-citizens – 
PCT Applications by Nationality – 1998 to 2006](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7cOJ.png)

Source: 
http://sites.kauffman.org/pdf/entrep_immigrants_1_61207.pdf

Comment: In case the referenced link goes 404, the title of the paper is "America’s New Immigrant Entrepreneurs" (January 4, 2007) on the letterhead of 
"Master of Engineering Management Program, Duke University; School of Information, U.C. Berkeley" with electronic copy available at http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=990152